# Why this series of commands is not working

Tags: vim

I am trying to create a command which copies current line to new tab, then breaks it at full stops (`.`), then adds a blank line below (at end of text) and finally goes to the beginning of the text (first line). I am using following code:

```
command Lnew y | tabnew | pu | s/\. /\r\r/g | noh | o | 1G
```

It works till `noh` part but the `o` and `1G` parts are not working. Where is the problem?

Comment: Too lazy to comb through manuals, but I suspect it fails because `o` and `1G` are normal-mode commands, and `command` expects a series of ex commands.

Comment: OK. Going through ex-commands displayed by `:help holy-grail` I find that `goto 1` takes cursor to start of text. However, I cannot find an ex-command that will insert a blank line below current line (like `o` in normal mode).

Comment: There's always `normal` to do whatever you can in normal mode as an ex command.

Comment: Thanks. The command `normal o` works but then next part does not get executed: `<ESC> goto 1`. The command `normal o <ESC> 1G` also only inserts a line but does not take cursor to first line of new tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command is an hybrid of Ex commands and normal mode commands. You have two options:

- only use Ex commands

  ```
  y | tabnew | put | s/\. /\r\r/g | nohlsearch | put='' | 1
  ```
- prepend your normal mode commands with `:help :normal`

  ```
  y | tabnew | put | s/\. /\r\r/g | nohlsearch | normal! o^O1G
  ```

  Use `<C-v><C-o>` to insert the literal `^O`.

Comment: Yes. I like the ex command version. It will be great if you can explain more on using normal commands in situations like this.

Comment: What kind of explanation do you want?

Answer (score 2):

A possible refinement:

```
command! Lnew y | tabnew | pu  | -d | s/\. /\r/g | noh | pu=''  | 1
```

The Ex 'put' command adds a new line above the copied line. Adding '-d' command addresses this.

By my reading the question asks about splitting at full stop and adding a blank line at end of text. It would seem only one '\r' is needed in the substitute command.

Comment: I want to add a blank line also to clearly separate sentences.

Answer (score 1):

In your Find-and-Replace command, it's also necessary to skip spaces, so instead of:

```
s/\. /\r\r/g
```

you'd have to use:

```
s/\.\ /\r\r/g
```

I was struggling with that for quite some time in my early days of Vim. Hope this helps.

Comment: It seems to working for me even without escaping space with '\'